# Excel VLOOKUP inconsistent results

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I am trying to make a simple gradebook using VLOOKUP in Excel for a class, but for some reason, some of my entries are getting a #N/A error while others find the correct value. Any ideas or suggestions on how I went wrong would be appreciated. Below is the formula and a link to the workbook itself.

```
=VLOOKUP([@GPA],J9:K21, 2, TRUE)
```

http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=61517379121210655491

Comment: make sure that the values are the same. Check for spaces or invisible character like spaces. additionally if you drag down the formula fix the range of your using $ ($J$9:$K$21)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change your data range to absolute references, using the $dollar symbol, at least in front of the row numbers:

```
=VLOOKUP([@GPA],J$9:K$21, 2, TRUE)
```